# How to pass return false using ng-click angular on the visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, javascript, service-cloud-console

I have a  requirement to open a primary tab by clicking on anchor tag.

It is happening but if I come back to the previous tab it's getting changed like primary tab. I know the issue is we have to pass **return true** while calling **OpenPrimaryTab()**.

```
<tr ng-repeat="case in Caseinformation|orderBy:sortType:sortReverse |      filter:query " style="height:1px;" class="data-row">          
     <td style="text-align:left;"><a ng-href="/{{case.caseId}}" ng-click= "openPrimaryCaseTab(case.caseId,case.caseNumber);return false">{{case.CaseNumber}}</a></td>
```

//Javascript

```
$scope.openPrimaryCaseTab = function (recordID,caseNumber) {
    alert('open primary tab'+recordID);
    sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(null,recordID,true,caseNumber); 
    }
```

`return false` is not working in ng-click, please suggest some workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Try below approach:

```
<tr ng-repeat="case in Caseinformation|orderBy:sortType:sortReverse |      filter:query " style="height:1px;" class="data-row">          
     <td style="text-align:left;"><a ng-href="/{{case.caseId}}" ng-click= " return openPrimaryCaseTab(case.caseId,case.caseNumber);">{{case.CaseNumber}}</a></td>
```

Angular Function:

```
$scope.openPrimaryCaseTab = function (recordID,caseNumber) {
    alert('open primary tab'+recordID);
    sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(null,recordID,true,caseNumber); 
    return false; // or any value based on
    }
```

`sforce.console.openPrimaryTab` return true/false based on tab is opened or not.

Comment: I changed my code according to your suggestion but now i am not able to open a primary tab page is opening in same view.

Comment: Looks like you need to manage `return false; // or any value based on`. Also check the console, you should not get any error by Angualr JS @lokeshkumar

Comment: if I am putting return before method I am getting the parse error. could you please tell how I put return false. @Ashwani